# Download Table from Webpage to Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I tried this below code. which is extracting detail from web page in table format.
**I'm receiving this error:** "Method 'open' of object 'IServerXMLHTTPRequest2'" failed
Please help me with this.

```
Dim htm As Object
Dim Tr As Object
Dim Td As Object
Dim Tab1 As Object

'Replace the URL of the webpage that you want to download
Web_URL = vba.Trim(Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1))

'Create HTMLFile Object
Set HTML_Content = CreateObject("htmlfile")

'Get the WebPage Content to HTMLFile Object
With CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
    .Open "GET", Web_URL, True
    .Send
    HTML_Content.Body.Innerhtml = .responseText
End With

Column_Num_To_Start = 1
iRow = 2
iCol = Column_Num_To_Start
iTable = 0

'Loop Through Each Table and Download it to Excel in Proper Format
For Each Tab1 In HTML_Content.getElementsByTagName("table")
    With HTML_Content.getElementsByTagName("table")(iTable)
        For Each Tr In .Rows
            For Each Td In Tr.Cells
                Sheets(1).Cells(iRow, iCol).Select
                Sheets(1).Cells(iRow, iCol) = Td.innerText
                iCol = iCol + 1
            Next Td
            iCol = Column_Num_To_Start
            iRow = iRow + 1
        Next Tr
    End With
    iTable = iTable + 1
    iCol = Column_Num_To_Start
    iRow = iRow + 1
Next Tab1
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the value of `Web_URL` when it fails?  And the `True` in that line should probably be `False`